# Export anonymous function from Package

Tags: perl, anonymous-function, perl-module

I got a package, lets call it Foo.pm for simplicity. In there, I got some Anonymous functions which I'd like to export.

Foo.pm looks like the following:

```
package Foo;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = ();
our @EXPORT = qw(
    subroutine1
    subroutine2

    $anon_function
);

subroutine1 {
    # Do something here
}

subroutine2 {
    # Do something else here
}

my $anon_function = sub {
    my $parameter = shift;

    # Do something with parameter

    return 1 if $parameter == 1 or $parameter == 2;
    return 0;
}
```

In my main script, call it bar.pl, im importing the module and (obviously) using its functions.

bar.pl:

```
use lib "/usr/share";
use Foo;

subroutine1("foobar");
subroutine2("foobar");

&$anon_function("foobar");
```

Using the normal subroutines outside of Foo.pm seems no problem, when I get to the `&$anon_function()` it produces the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at ./bar.pl line 7
```

When trying to print the anonymous function with `print Dumper \$anon_function`, it also returns `$VAR1 = \undef`

**TL;DR**: How can I Export anonymous functions from a Package?

Comment: You cannot export a lexical variable. You can only export symbols, i.e. package global variables and named subroutines.

Comment: @choroba so, if I understood correctly, changing `my $anon_function` to `our $anon_function` does the job?

Comment: It should, yes.

Comment: That's defying the point of masking the sub "anonymous"!

Comment: @ikegami I know! Unfortunately, its very old (and sometimes very bad) code written by people who are now triple my age, and I have to maintain it. Hoping to be allowed to rewrite it soon!

Comment: @noah We're talking about a new code here. It obviously wasn't exported before. As such, `*named_function = $anon_function;` and export `named_function`.

Comment: @ikegami If I was in charge of deciding how its done, I would have rewritten the entire Script in python. But my task is to get the tests running asap, which means I cant really focus on clean code that much. Since there is short of 100 functions we are talking about, I dont really feel like changing them all.

Comment: What I suggested is not clean code. It's a quick way of not making things worse. And introducing something to fix. /// There's these things called loops... 10 or 100, it's all the same. I'm actually showing how to *avoid* making 100s of changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot export a lexical variable. You can only export symbols, i.e. package global variables and named subroutines.

Changing to an [our](http://p3rl.org/our) works:

```perl
use Exporter qw{ import };
our @EXPORT = qw( $anon );
our $anon = sub { ... };
```